# SQL Server Aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregation

I have a table that has 3 columns: Customers, BillingDate, Consumption

```
CITY - PARKS/6TH AVE BMX PARK   2013-04-29 00:00:00.000 0
CITY - PARKS/6TH AVE BMX PARK   2013-04-29 00:00:00.000 30
CITY - PARKS/6TH AVE BMX PARK   2013-05-30 00:00:00.000 0
CITY - PARKS/6TH AVE BMX PARK   2013-05-30 00:00:00.000 19500
CITY - PARKS/6TH AVE BMX PARK   2013-06-28 00:00:00.000 0
CITY - PARKS/6TH AVE BMX PARK   2013-06-28 00:00:00.000 42100
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2012-11-27 00:00:00.000 0
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2012-11-27 00:00:00.000 8900
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2012-12-27 00:00:00.000 0
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2012-12-27 00:00:00.000 7900
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2013-01-28 00:00:00.000 0
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2013-01-28 00:00:00.000 3090
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2013-01-28 00:00:00.000 7210
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2013-02-28 00:00:00.000 0
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2013-02-28 00:00:00.000 10100
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2013-03-29 00:00:00.000 0
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2013-03-29 00:00:00.000 6700
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2013-04-29 00:00:00.000 0
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2013-04-29 00:00:00.000 9100
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2013-05-30 00:00:00.000 0
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2013-05-30 00:00:00.000 11100
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2013-06-28 00:00:00.000 0
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2013-06-28 00:00:00.000 12700
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2012-07-27 00:00:00.000 0
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2012-08-27 00:00:00.000 0
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2012-08-27 00:00:00.000 1630
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 0
```

Since I have same BillingDate for the same customer, I want to sum the consuption based on the matching BillingDate. This should give me the following:

```
CITY - PARKS/6TH AVE BMX PARK   2013-04-29 00:00:00.000 30
CITY - PARKS/6TH AVE BMX PARK   2013-05-30 00:00:00.000 19500
CITY - PARKS/6TH AVE BMX PARK   2013-06-28 00:00:00.000 42100
CITY - FIRE STATION #3  2012-11-27 00:00:00.000 8900
```

and so on....

I posted a similar question but I really did not get what I am looking for. Thank you SQL experts.

Comment: Then you should try to give more information if you don't get desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I haven't missed something

```
select Customers, BillingDate, sum(Consumption)
from Table1
group by Customers, BillingDate
```

Answer (score 2):

It'd be something like:

```
Select
Customers, BillingDate, sum(Consumption)
from [Table]
group by Customers, BillingDate
```